# How to get the callback value of function that is inside an another function?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two functions **updateSpeaker()**,**uploadSpeakerImageAdd()** I want to upload the image to the webapi and get the filename as callback and i want to post the filename within the  **updateSpeaker()** .

**updateSpeaker()**

```
   updateSpeaker(menuItem)
        { 

          this.uploadSpeakerImageAdd();
          console.log(this.imagename)
        let update_event_speakers_body={
                '_id':this.menuItem.id,
                'name':this.menuItem.name,
                'matter':this.menuItem.matter,
                'image':this.imagename,       //file name getting from the uploadSpeakerImageAdd().
                'session':this.menuItem.session,
                'link':this.menuItem.link,
                'event_id':this.EventId };
        this.getPostMenuService.doUpdateSpeakers(update_event_speakers_body).subscribe(
                    data => {
                    console.log(data);
                   },err => {
                    console.log("error")
                  });

        }
```

**uploadSpeakerImageAdd()**

```
 uploadSpeakerImageAdd() {
    let inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
    let fileCount: number = inputEl.files.length;
    console.log(fileCount);
    let formData = new FormData();
    if (fileCount > 0) { // a file was selected
        for (let i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
            formData.append('file[]', inputEl.files.item(i));
        }

        this.getPostMenuService.doPostImage( formData).subscribe(data => {



                        this.imagename=data.file;
                       console.log( this.imagename);

                   },
            err => {
             console.log("error")

          }); 
     }


  }
```

This code is working but only getting the file name after the execution of **updateSpeaker()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function as argument to `uploadSpeakerImageAdd()`

```
updateSpeaker(menuItem){ 
    this.uploadSpeakerImageAdd(function(imageName){
        // You get file name here so create the body object and do Post call.
    });
}
```

You will be passing the anonymous function as callback to `uploadSpeakerImageAdd` function.

```
uploadSpeakerImageAdd(callback) {
    // perform all the logic before post call 

    this.getPostMenuService.doPostImage( formData).subscribe(data => {
            // Pass the image name to callback
            callback(data.file);
        },
        err => {
         console.log("error")
      });
```

### Using Reactive Programming

If you like to do the same using reactive programming , it will be like this:

```
updateSpeaker(menuItem){ 
    this.uploadSpeakerImageAdd()
        .subscribe(file => {
             // you get the file object, create the body and do Post call
        });
}
```

Inside `uploadSpeakerImageAdd` method, instead of subscribing , you just return the observable:

```
uploadSpeakerImageAdd() {
    // perform all the logic before post call 
    return this.getPostMenuService.doPostImage( formData);
}
```

Comment: Getting  "EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'imagename' of undefined" Error

Comment: You dont need to use `this.imagename` anywhere. updated the code

Answer (score 0):

From your html part , fire change event like this:

```
<input type="file" (change)="uploadSpeakerImageAdd($event)" value="file">

And in your component or controller:

uploadSpeakerImageAdd($event): void {
   let inputValue: any;
   inputValue = $event.target;
   this.file = inputValue.files[0];

   this.getPostMenuService.doPostImage(this.file)
    .subscribe(
     data => {
       this.imagename=data.file;
     },
     error => {

     };

    });
}
```

Call your uploadSpeakerImageAdd on `change` event.